# How to create a JSON array of dictionaries in jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a treeview structure in html. It will only have nodes, and subnodes. It can't have another sublevel. One of the features of this treeview is that users can rearrange the nodes and subnodes.

When the user saves it, I will make it send a JSON object to my c# page, and in the server it will read the new order and save it. The order is determined by the order of the objects in the JSON object.

I picture the JSON object will look like this (example):

```
[ {id: 4, items: [5, 6, 7]}, {id: 8, items: [9, 10, 11, 12, ...]}, ... ]
```

So it would be an array of dictionaries. For each dictionary, it will have two keys, the `id` will be the id number of the node, and the `items` will be an array of the id's of the subnodes.

It's important that the order is the same as the order I add to the array, so that when I iterate through them, its still in the same order when I inserted them. If its like a dictionary then this wont be true.

Im pretty sure I can create this array of dictionaries using jquery. But how can I turn this into a JSON object? Is this possible?

And in c#, how would I be able to read this?

Comment: You may be interested to look up the DefaultModelBinder for C# with JSON, in order to send a Post back to a Controller that populates your C# class with the JSON data, but i've provided you a simple solution to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

_ really don't see the problem.  If you're using jQuery you're using Javascript.  A JSON object *is* a Javascript object, so the following would be valid in jQuery.  It will serialize the object into a string.

```
var data = [ {id: 4, items: [5, 6, 7]}, {id: 8, items: [9, 10, 11, 12, ...]}, ... ];
$.post({ 
     data: data,
     // ...
});
```

If you need the string, JSON.Stringify() will turn the object into a string.  (I didn't realize it was native to Javascript).  Never had too since I've been always using jQuery ajax.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of parsing this data in C# would to use a library such as JSON.Net. You are able to parse a json string and traverse through this without having to actually mirror this JSON structure you have to actual C# Classes, however this can become helpful with large amounts of Json.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{ items: [ {id: 4, items: [5, 6, 7]}, 
          {id: 8, items: [9, 10, 11, 12]}, {id: 5, items: [9, 10, 11, 12]} ] }";

    JToken root = JToken.Parse(json);
    JToken items = root["items"];

    var results = from element in items
                  select new
                  {
                     Id = element["id"].Value<int>(),
                     Items = element["items"].Select(x => x.Value<int>())
                  };

    foreach (var r in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Items: {1}", r.Id, string.Join(", ", r.Items));
    }
}
```

Prints to console:

```
Id: 4, Items: 5, 6, 7
Id: 8, Items: 9, 10, 11, 12
Id: 5, Items: 9, 10, 11, 12
```

Another handy utility I like to use is [Json2C#](http://json2csharp.com/), which gives me a foundation. But the example I have provided shows you a lightweight, fast approach to retrieving your data after you have sent a HTTP Post request.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

**Question 1**

> But how can I turn this into a JSON object? Is this possible?

Answer

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObjList = jss .Serialize(objList);
```

**Question 2**

> And in c#, how would I be able to read this?

**Answer**

*Model*

```
public class Object1
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public List<int> items {get; set;}
}
```

*Logic*

```
string jsonData = @"[ {id: 4, items: [5, 6, 7]}, {id: 8, items: [9, 10, 11, 12, ...]}, ... ]";

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var objList = jss.Deserialize<List<Object1 >>(jsonData);
```

Comment: How would I loop through all the values?

Comment: @omega you may use **foreach** like this `foreach(var obj in objList)`

Comment: How can I deserialize the string, if I create the string manually?

Comment: **jsonData** - the datatype of this variable is a `String`