# How to extract numbers from string array/dictionary using c#?

Tags: c#, json, string-parsing

I have a string where its a string of a array of dictionaries.

An example of the format is:

```
[{"id":1,"items":[5,8]},{"id":2,"items":[6]},{"id":3,"items":[7]}]
```

(Note: all the above code is a string)

So here it is a string of an array of dictionaries that has two keys, the value of the first key is a number, and the value of the second key is a array of numbers.

Using c# (out of the box assemblies), how can I iterate through all the id values, and then all the item array values.

So I would expect like a double for loop. One to iterate through the id's and extract the number, and then for each iteration it would need to iterate through all the values of the items array.

Does anyone know how to go about parsing and extracting the numbers?

Thanks.

The output would be like ( for example )

```
1
 5  8
2
 6
3
 7
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
            string dataString = JSONValue.Text;
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = json.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, Object>>>(dataString);

            int sectionID;
            List<int> itemIDS;
            foreach (Dictionary<string, Object> dict in data)
            {
                sectionID = (int)dict["id"];
                itemIDS = (List<int>)dict["items"];
                ReportObject.log(sectionID.ToString());
                foreach (int itemID in itemIDS)
                {
                    ReportObject.log(itemID.ToString());
                }
            }
```

But am getting

```
(6/27/2013 12:02:04 AM) - Error Message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.
```

Comment: That’s JSON — are you looking for a way to parse it, or have you parsed it and are looking for a way to loop through it? If it’s the former, Google “C# JSON parsing” and you’ll find a lot of helpful information, including [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/), which is pretty good.

Comment: Isn't that JSON? You could use external JSON libraries with that...

Comment: I already stringified it, now I got the string of it in c#, and want to extract the intergers from it in c#.

Comment: I was hoping to do this without external libraries.

Comment: There is a library for JSON that is not external, `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: The text in the code blocks that you posted is JSON. You can easily parse JSON with c#. I think there is internal deserialization library for JSON in .net.

Comment: I was looking at the post by loy here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332642/how-to-create-a-json-array-of-dictionaries-in-jquery#17334013, but it seems to work if the page got a JSON post. In my case I have the string received not by a JSON post.

Comment: I updated my first post with my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
using using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var jsonStr = "[{\"id\":1,\"items\":[5,8]},{\"id\":2,\"items\":[6]},{\"id\":3,\"items\":[7]}]";
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = json.Deserialize<List<dynamic>>(jsonStr);
```

this will generate a list of dynamic object with two properties `id` and `items`, then you can loop through that list and retrieve the info which you want.

The `dynamic` keyword only available from .net 4.0 or later. Otherwise you can use the following option.

create a class like this

```
public class Info{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then `var data = json.Deserialize<List<Info>>(jsonStr);`

Comment: The namespace dynamic is undefined.

Comment: which .net framework you are using, it's available from .net 4.0 or more

Comment: I updated my answer above, with an error message I am getting. I am using .net 3.5.

Comment: use my second option for this case

Comment: Then how do I loop through all the values like I tried in my example?

Answer (score 0):

try getting the int value of string, if it's an array, get the object on the index specifically and try to the `ToInt()` or cast the string object to int. it can be done both ways.